# Why doesn't a URL with two hyphens ( in one segment ) match a Route in my Route Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes, url-routing

I'm trying to resolve this URL Route:

```
Route articlesByCategory = new Route("articles/c{cid}-{category}", new Handler);
```

However, it seems like the following url won't resolve to this route:

```
// doesn't work
www.site.com/articles/c24-this-is-the-category-title

// This works
www.site.com/articles/c24-category
```

I assume it has to do with the dashes in the title, but can anyone tell me why this works this way?

Is there a way to allow dashes in the title for a URL route like this?

Comment: Have you come across this yet?

http://blog.zero7web.com/2010/02/how-to-allow-hyphens-in-urls-using-asp-net-mvc-2/

Comment: Might as well have posted that link as answer and marked this as a duplicate of the SO question mentioned ;)

Comment: Thanks xander, I hadn't seen that yet. I'm going to try that out. @Morten. Not really an SO duplicate, that's on a different site.

Comment: @xander. That solution is directed at MVC which has routes mapping to classes ( which can't handle hyphens ). However, since I'm mapping to an aspx page, that isn't a concern. The problem is that the URL I specified doesn't match against the route above ( or any other route ). I think it has to do with the URL Route parser, Perhaps it parses from RTL and can't determine where the category id is in the segment?

Comment: @Atomiton: The link is to a different site, but that links back to a different SO question.

Comment: @Morten. Yeah... I ended up seeing that after all. However, the problem is with recognizing the route in the first place. It doesn't match any of the routes, so I'm not even getting to this step in the first place. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Which hyphen is the delimiter?

Server doesn't know which hyphen in your URL is delimiting `cid` from `category`. That's why it can't work. You could solve this by using something else than dashes in your category value. **Or** write a custom Route class that will be more flexible with definitions.

[This answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378222#2380820) may help you, because it can easily be used in your case...

Comment: I have a constraint on {cid} which only allows numbers. It's prefaced by c.  I would have assumed it would have used a regular expression like "articles/c[0-9]{1,6}-.*/" behind the scenes but I'm don't know enough about how the Routing engine matches routes to know exactly. It would appear to only respect the forward slash as a concrete delimiter.

Comment: Just checked out that answer. RegexRoute... interesting.

Comment: @Atomiton: Constraints are checked **after** route has already determined that a particular request should be handled by this route (by it's URL definition). Steps: Route tries to parse incoming request against its URL definition. If parsing succeeds, URL variables (as defined in route URL definition) are checked against constraints. In your particular case, parsing fails. Constraint checking does not execute at all.

Comment: Excellent comment! I had assumed it worked like a Regex, but your explanation makes more sense, now. I'm also thinking it parses from RTL. Have you got a source for more information about how it works? I saw your post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378222#answer-2381181 on the other question. Also very helpful. Thanks!