# ASP.Net MVC: How to use a virtual path (directory) with a dot (period)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing

If I create a new MVC web application project, build and run it the home page comes up as expected.  However, if you change the project's Web Properties to use a "Virtual Path" that contains a dot (for example: "Version1.2"), it will fail to work ("The resource cannot be found.").

What options are there?

Answer (score 0):

Using something else instead of a dot, maybe? ;)

### Custom Route class

You could write custom route class and provide you own functionality that will be able to consume URLs with dots. But be warned: writing a custom Route class requires a bit deeper understanding of Asp.net routing than just `routes.MapRoute()`.

I've done a custom Route class in the past. It serves a different purpose, but you can check it out. Maybe it will lighten things up a bit for you. Click [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378222#2381181) and check it out.

Comment: Yes, that's an option but unfortunately, I need the dots.

Any suggestions on example custom route classes?

Thanks!

Comment: @jbierling: I added a link to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is automatically generated you could add a slash at the end of the url. Ending the URL with a slash prevents the routing system from trying to look it up as a file even though the last component of the URL contains a dot.

For example, use this URL :

http://www.example.com/version1.2/